Power Automate flow to save excel file individually from AI Builder document processing
I am new to Power Automate and would like to ask some queries about it. I have worked on my test environment to run automation using Power Automate to extract data from PDF documents and save the extracted data to Excel. My question is, what is the proper procedure in Power Automate to execute the flow and save the extracted data into individual Excel files?
Thank you an appreciate your feedback.
Currently, I have used a single Excel table to store all the extracted data by adding rows into a table, resulting in all data being merged into the same Excel file. Is it possible to save the data into individual Excel files instead?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
